# Python- Else error

Tags: python, if-statement

I am very bad at python [Learning to code] and I made a guess-a-number script, but when I ran it I got this:

```
  File "guess-a-num.py", line 15
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the part I probably messed up on:

```
if ask == number:
    print("You got it!")
    print("Thanks for playing!")
raw_input("")
quit


else:
    print("Nope! 3 tries left!")
    ask == raw_input("?")
    if ask == number:
        print("You got it in 2 tries!")
        raw_input()
        quit
```

Comment: Indentation, my friend.  The indentation already _completes_ the `if` condition.

Comment: A bit more specific? I looked into that already, Couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Bump `raw_input("")` and `quit` in a bit and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ask == number:
    print("You got it!")
    print("Thanks for playing!")
    raw_input("")
    quit
else:
    print("Nope! 3 tries left!")
    ask == raw_input("?")
    if ask == number:
        print("You got it in 2 tries!")
        raw_input()
        quit
```